# Problema al iterar sobre una lista de DataFrames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

En el script siguiente, al iterar sobre una lista de DataFrames, solamente me devuelve el contenido del primero y del último. ¿Cuál puede ser la causa?

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start_day = "2000-1-4"
end_day = date.today()
    
dicc_tickers = {"IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "TEF.MC":"Telefonica", "R4.MC":"Renta4", "^IBEX":"Ibex35", "^GSPC":"S&P500", 
                "^IXIC":"Nasdaq", "^N225":"Nikkey_225", "^DJI":"DowJons", "^STOXX50E":"Eurostoxx50",  
                "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", "IBE.MC":"Iberdrola", 
                'AAPL':"Apple", 'MSFT':"Microsoft", 'GOOG':"Google", "AMZN":"Amazon"}

dfs = []    
for (key,value) in dicc_tickers.items():
    #cotizaciones_de_ticker = pdr.DataReader(k, 'yahoo', start, end)
    cotizaciones = yf.download(key, start= start_day, end = end_day)
    cotizaciones = cotizaciones[["Close"]]
    cotizaciones = cotizaciones.rename(columns={"Close": value})
                                                              
    dfs.append(cotizaciones)
        
dfs = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs)
for df_ in dfs:
    df_yf_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Date')

df_yf_final
```

Devuelve:

[image: DataFrame devuelto]

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira en detalle esto:

```
dfs = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs)
for df_ in dfs:
    df_yf_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Date')
```

`df_yf_final` con cada iteración va siendo el primer `dataframe`, con el leído en el ciclo, por lo que finalmente tendrás solo el primer y último objeto de la lista. Podrías resolverlo de esta forma:

```
dfs_iter = iter(dfs)
df_final = next(dfs_iter)
for df_ in dfs_iter:
    df_final = df_final.merge(df_, on='Date')

df_final
```

Esta básicamente entiendo era tu idea, pero ten en cuenta que no es una buena práctica ya que estas creando objetos en memorias de volumen creciente, cada iteración crea y copia los datos de `df_final`  a un nuevo `df_final`, ya que tienes una lista, me parece que lo más adecuado sería concatenar cada objeto de la lista en un único `dattaframe`:

```
pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Comment: Gracias. Además, con 'merge', a veces hay problema con el nombre de las columnas.